# Reset A Form: Elements with style="display:none"

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, button, reset

Working on a Reset button for a form. So on my .jsp I have this line:

```
<input type="reset"  class="primary" value="Reset Form"><br>
```

And this reverts all user input data. However there are also buttons on this form. Email, Fax and Telephone buttons. If the user selects Telephone, Another set of buttons appear: Morning and Evening

If I click on Telephone and I click "Reset" the buttons do become 'un-clicked' yet the meny with Morning and Evening buttons remains. Any input on this as to why it is?

Comment: Without any code it's impossible to say.

Comment: Could you provide a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) example?

Comment: `If the user selects Telephone, Another set of buttons appear` Is the new appearance done by vanilla CSS or with _JavaScript_? If it's _JavaScript_, you'll need to have some reverse-function which is applied on the `<form>` reset, too.

Comment: Post your code, you might just need to remove those 2 sets of buttons on submit.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to incorporate [RobG's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) comment:

> ``A *[reset button](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/forms.html#reset-button-state-%28type=reset%29)* **only** resets the value of controls, it doesn't do anything else. It was invented before there was scripting available, so it just does a basic job. If you want any other functionality, you'll need to program it.''

This sums up the why.

If we take a look at the [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc.html) for [Hypertext Markup Language - 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866), (*note that this is an obsoleted document*) we find:

- 8.1.2.8. [Reset Button: INPUT TYPE=RESET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866#section-8.1.2.8)

And as the abstract section of the document say: *``This specification roughly corresponds to the capabilities of HTML in common use prior to June 1994.''* Also look at the [*Acknowledgments*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866#section-12) section of the document.

[Here](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/HTMLPlus/htmlplus_41.html#htmlplus_FootNote_117) is another example from 1993.

The appearance of scripting languages in web browsers, such as [ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) => Javascript, [JSCript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript), etc. fully started to appear from the mid 1990's, and trough time the ability to further manipulate the document in a dynamic way trough the [DOM (Document Object Model)](http://www.w3.org/DOM/#what).

However, the HTML standard to this day still has a predefined set of elements that [can be reset in a form](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#category-reset) trough the click of a reset button.

---

#### As for the issue at hand

Add an event listener for reset and add style `display:none` to the buttons, or the wrapper of the buttons.

```
var form = document.getElementById("someform");
form.addEventListener("reset", hide_day);
```

See [here for compatibility cases](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) when it comes to `addEventListener`. [This](https://gist.github.com/eduardocereto/955642) should go a long way.

And/Or use the `onreset` attribute for the form directly.

<kbd>[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/pY9g4/)</kbd>

There is also the possibility of [using a library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries#DOM_.28manipulation.29_related) to ease and abstract away the challenges that comes with making a script work on as many systems and web browsers as possible. For example such things as adding event listener to document objects.

Though fiddling with this from scratch can be a challenge, it is also educational :)

Comment: @RobG: No, it surely doesn't. Can I embed your comment under question? It was nicely written.